# Managed service identity in Windows container using service fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, windows-container, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to call MSI from the container on a VM inside a service fabric cluster. I am able to get the token from the host using:
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:50342/oauth2/token -Method GET -Body @{resource="https://management.azure.com/"} -Headers @{Metadata="true"}

However, when I try to invoke the same service from the container using the IP address of the Gateway it doesn't work. Is there a feature on MSI roadmap to support containers in the VM host machine?

Comment: can you try it using localhost?

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work from the container. Works fine from the host machine.